# Using value from Excel cell as filter in MS Power Query

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery

I got an excel file which should use a query from an ms access file (which is a front end for a ms sql server)
But instead of receiving every entry I want to use a filter by a value that is in one of the excel cells.
So if in A1 is date 01.01.2000, I want to use this value to only show me all entries by that date

If do not need to use power query if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: I just tried building Power Query to pull from Access db linked SQLServer tables and linked tables are not available. Are you able to pull from linked tables?

Comment: Use the query how? Are you opening a recordset object? It's fairly simple in VBA to establish connection to db and build SQL string with WHERE clause referencing cell and linked tables can be referenced.

Comment: I am creating my custom queries to run a query and run them by Invoked Custom Function. Search for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a value into power query using a table and have your original query reference that cell/table. More detail here: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/pass-excel-parameter-power-query/

Answer (score -1):

check the sample file, fill the parameters as per your DataBase

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nhB710FEl_AfFQy6HwDmR8xhcWWuw91p/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100599386090580961037&rtpof=true&sd=true